# UnicodeDecodeError while using pip install in virtualenv

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, virtualenv, decode

I am installing Nucypher in a virtual environment and getting the `UnicodeDecodeError` as shown below:

Command:

```
python -m pip install nucypher
```

Output:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 178, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 352, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 131, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 294, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 362, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 171, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.prepare_metadata()
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 553, in prepare_metadata
    metadata_name = canonicalize_name(self.metadata["Name"])
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 674, in metadata
    self._metadata = get_metadata(self.get_dist())
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in get_metadata
    metadata = dist.get_metadata('METADATA')
  File "C:\Users\PRANIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1420, in get_metadata
    return value.decode('utf-8') if six.PY3 else value
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 185: invalid continuation byte
```

I am using windows 10, pip 19.1.1.
I didn't get this error while installing `Numpy` in the same virtual environment. Please suggest as to what needs to be done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just moved from Mac to Windows and I was facing the exact same issue when using PowerShell and `virtualenv`. I have switched to use the command line instead with the built-in `venv` and it worked. It might be worth giving it a try if you are not fixed on `virtualenv`.